# Избежать дубликатов Stylus после преобразования в .css

Tags: css, gulp, stylus

В `Stylus`, в разных файлах, есть `@-moz-document url-prefix()` с стилями для определенных классов.

`f1.style`:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
   .f1
       color green
```

`f2.styl`:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
   .f2
       color yellow
       display flex
```

В результате, это все есть в одном файле, но не множество классов со стилями под `@-moz-document url-prefix()`, а множество `@-moz-document url-prefix()` с соответствующими классами.

Как поместить все под `@-moz-document url-prefix()` и избежать повторений?

В Css должно появиться:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix()
       .f1
           color green
       .f2
           color yellow
           display flex
```

Но не:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix()
       .f1
           color green
 @-moz-document url-prefix()
       .f2
           color yellow
           display flex
```

И, могу ли я сделать `mixin` добавляющий `@-moz-document url-prefix()` и определенные классы внутри него?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете сборку с помощью gulp, советую добавить в сборщик плагин [gulp-group-css-media-queries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-group-css-media-queries). Он комбинирует все одинаковые media в один:

```
var
   gulp = require('gulp'),
   stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),
   gs = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries');

gulp.task('css', function() {
   gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
      .pipe(stylus({
         use: nib()
      }))
      .pipe(cmq())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за плагин! Хотя, работает код только от сюда https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-combine-mq - что Ваш код делает? и почему-то вообще не добавляет `@supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar)` при сборке